# Why does the Amazonian nation have zero population?

Tags: dc

From [a blog post in 2008](http://blog.smartmemes.com/2008/10/dcu-decisions-staggers-to-a-conclusion/)

> In #3, ... as Wonder Woman offered a very cogent argument ...  about why she shouldn’t endorse any candidate, being a diplomatic representative of the Amazon nation (**never mind that her nation currently has zero population**)

Why does the nation have zero population? Did all the Amazons get killed? Exiled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That comic, DCU Decisions #3 2008 is set during Wonder Woman Vol 3 #22 (or so) As a result of the Amazons Attack story line, set around Wonder Woman Vol 3. #16 (or so):

> Athena appears, displeased with what the Amazons have done and prepared to pass judgment. Circe is banished to Hades. Themyscira rises from the ocean. The Amazons disappear to parts unknown. Hippolyta is exiled to rule over an empty Themyscira.
>
> Athena watches events unfold, with the Greek gods in chains behind her. She reveals that the Amazons have been turned into regular mortal women scattered throughout the world with no memory of their past lives.

Due to behind the scenes manipulation, Themyscira has been depopulated, while Diana and Donna still around in the U.S. This gets resolved a few arcs later, involving Darkseid.

This series ended with the New 52 reboot, and everything changed.

Comment: Less is more.  Thanks to localizing to the context I was interested in

Answer (score 5):

#### Wonder Woman's home of Themyscira has, over its long history but primarily after the Crisis on Infinite Earths reboot, been destroyed or in varying states of flux (not in our dimension, completely destroyed, moved to outer space, or the Themyscirans were killed or awaiting rebirth through divine magic).

[image]

- It is possible the article writer may have been discussing one of those periods where the Amazons of Themyscira were unavailable or simply did not exist for a time.
- The Amazons of Themyscira have had multiple origins, many of them implying they are not living beings but constructs of stone or earth whose bodies house the spirits of women murdered by men.
- Modern writers have made Themyscira a regular battleground where the inhabitants are constantly under threat of destruction. In almost any movie Themyscira appears in, it is either invaded or attacked by someone.
- In many of the origins of Themyscira, the Amazons are technically not human, the article could have meant zero population growth, not zero population.
- Since the reboot, the Themyscirans have a different origin and actually need men to procreate, but kill the men when they are done with them... This will certainly change again...

> - **Darkseid’s forces ravaged Themyscira during a search to locate the Greek gods, killing nearly half of the Amazons there in the process. As they began rebuilding, the Amazons found themselves reverting to stone.**

[image]

> - This was as a result of the gods’ departure from the mortal plane, and the Amazons’ connection to their creator beings so diminished as to revert their bodies to their primordial state. With the gods returned to Olympus, the Amazons were once again transformed into their flesh and blood state.
> - Yet more Amazons were killed in a confrontation with the demonic entity known as Neron.

In other conflicts:

> - With Diana and Hippolyta adventuring in Patriarch’s World as Wonder Woman for longer and longer periods of time, the Banas and the Themyscirans were manipulated into a bloody civil war at the hands of Magala, who had been possessed by the spirit of Antiope’s murderer, Ariadne.
> - Using the pre-existing disdain of the tribes against each other, Magala used allies among both Amazon cities to spark the vengeful conflict. The island was left in ruins, and the war was only stopped when Hippolyta abolished the royal family, renounced her throne.
>     Left at odds but on even political ground, the Bana Amazons and the Themyscirans joined forces against the alien forces of Imperiex.
> - Themyscira, mystically moved into outer space, was destroyed, and hundreds of Amazons from both tribes died. When Wonder Woman led each tribe of Amazons into an ecumenical prayer, funneling power into the new god Darkseid, the warrior women helped destroy Imperiex and its ally Brainiac 13.

**REF: [Wikipedia > Themyscira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Themyscira_(DC_Comics))**

[image]

Comment: "actually need men to procreate, **but kill the men when they are done with them**". I am just imagining the outcry if someone came out with a media property where the male heroes had this with roles reversed.

Comment: You are never going to see that. And I believe DC will retconn this as soon as it is feasibly possible. I couldn't even believe they ALLOWED it to be said in print!

Comment: my comment was more on the state of modern political discourse (and feminism in particular) than on DC's poor editorial and creative judgement, which doesn't seem like it even needs to be commented on :)

Comment: @DVK: that's what Amazons (in the Greek legends) were actually doing. On the other hand, in the last Mad Max installment, we can see women enslaved for the need of repopulating the Earth, and AFAIK there isn't any scandal.

Comment: @Taladris - were the enslavers portrayed as protagonists?

Comment: @DVK: I didn't see the movie, just heard about the plot. I think they are enslaved by the main villain and  a big part of the plot is that the goal of the character portrayed by Charlize Theron is to free them.

Comment: @Taladris - yes, generally making a hubbub out of a villlain doing a bad thing isn't what happens. My point was that Amazons did a bad thing but since the victims were male nobody cares about it (and Amazons aren't villains)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it from a biological point of view it is a race of all women, and they are not scientifically advanced enough for artificial insemination or cloning. In the super friends original series Diana (wonder woman) was a statue brought to life by a spell but it is possible that the knowledge was lost

Comment: So... what happened to the rest of the women? Were they killed? Did they just die of natural causes? While related, this really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well in the new 52 they seduce, then kill (so basically rape) sailors, to get pregnant, and kill or sale off any male born children, while raising the female ones to be Amazons who eventually do the same in a few years